# NFS read-only export security considerations

Tags: security, nfs

Almost all articles about NFS security refer to clients faking uids to access files they are not supposed to.

My concerns are different. My only export is read-only and effectively public (not exposed to the internet, but the data are not secret at all and their others' read bit is set). The data is rarely modified on the server, if needed, I can make sure they are modified only when nfs-server is turned off. I therefore do not need locking.

In what ways can completely malicious clients negatively affect the server? I am mainly interested in security problems (accessing files outside of the export, writing to any files, RCE…), DoS is not critical to me, but I would nonetheless want the know about its possibilities.

**context**: I would like to offer netboot in my network, serving read-only base root filesystems over NFS and the clients would create in memory overlays above it. I have little control over the client machines.

Answer (score 0):

The read-only export is fully controlled by server independent from client sending a write request or faking the uids (assume, that server implementation is not badly broken). Thus, a malicious clients can't modify date in read-only export or escape the exported path. Moreover, you should export with `squash_all` option to map all users to `nobody` on the server independent from provided uids.

If you want to go completely paranoid about it, then you can mount the underlying filesystem system on the server as read-only before exporting it with NFS. A user-space NFS servers, like nfs-ganesha, that started with systemd can be additionally protected by the corresponding options `ReadWriteDirectories=`, `ReadOnlyDirectories=` and `InaccessibleDirectories=`